# AWS Access Prod Error Even with Access Enabled

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have requested and received AWS-SES prod access in OHIO region ( us-east-2 ), but even with the status changed to ENABLED on my account:

I still getting the error **Production access not granted. Please request production access prior to sending custom verification emails**

**I have generated a new SMTP keys settings.
I have forced the region using Regions.US_EAST_2.**

Is there anything more that I should to do?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood you question correct.

When you mention "status changed to ENABLED", I suppose you are talking about identity verification.

On console it can show as:

```
Enabled for Sending: Yes
Status: verified
```

or

```
Enabled for Sending: No
Status: pending verification
```

You have also a concept called `sandbox` and `production`. By default your account is on `sandbox`. You need to request it to be moved to `production` and provide a use-case in this request.

[image: SES account details]

They are different concepts, so for you to have full permissions to send e-mail, you need to have your identity verified and your account on production.

Based on your error message your account is not in production.
Your identity can be verified, but still in sandbox.